# Are we forbidden from striving to develop biotech that can make us immortal since that would essentially be like biting off from the Tree of Life?

Tags: halacha, technology, parashat-bereishit, health-safety-shmira

In the recent years, there has been a lot of talk and investment in the biotech space regarding life extension, with some saying that the eventual goal is to make us live forever. However, to strive to live forever could be interpreted as an attempt to take also of the tree of life and live forever, something which seems that G-d, blessed be He, doesn't want us to do as can be seen from Genesis 3:22 after the fall:

> lest he put forth his hand, and take also of the tree of life, and eat, and live for ever

Therefore, would we be forbidden from trying to develop such technology, and perhaps could we, at best, try to develop life saving or life-extending technologies that make our lifespans longer by a reasonable amount as opposed to forever? What do the texts say about this?

Comment: Haven't we already been developing these technologies for centuries? We call it "medicine"

Comment: @DoubleAA not exactly, medicine and helping people with poor health is not the same as intentionally striving for immortality.

Comment: Was Adam forbidden from eating from the Tree of Life?

Comment: @shmosel Well clearly if cherubim and a flaming sword are placed at the east end of the Garden to guard the way to the tree of life. The fact that such protection was placed shows that it's not to be eaten along with the quote I provided?

Comment: If there's a flaming sword in the way of technological immortality we'll know the answer.

Comment: @shmosel Not a helpful response, you're misinterpreting the concept of the flaming sword and the path to the tree, etc.

Comment: My point is Hashem chose to obstruct the path to immortality rather than forbid it. I don't see why technology would change that dynamic.

Comment: @shmosel Because the same reasons for why HaShem, blessed be He, obstructed immortality in the first place, could very well play out again with technologically-induced immortality.

Comment: According to the Midrash, Serach bas Asher was blessed by Yaakov to live forever. If there was any issue with such a thing, Yaakov wouldn’t of given such a blessing

Comment: Exactly my point. If He wants to obstruct our path, He'll do so. That's not a basis for assuming it's forbidden.

Comment: @setszu yes it is. We don't kill people but try to help them live as long as possible.

Comment: @DoubleAA living as long as possible is not the same as striving for immortality, etc. etc.

Comment: @setszu it literally is, etc. etc.

Comment: as Isaac Moses has pointed out, there's seemingly no prohibition. It comes across more like a curse, and we know that not only is it not forbidden, it's actually strongly encouraged that we reverse the curses. However, death seems to actually be a punishment, and we are not allowed to avoid a punishment. There is aggada that explains how our body needs to die in order to re-achieve certain true parts of its being (including immortality). I think it's a good question and would love to know if someone discusses this somewhere

Comment: @DoubleAA No it isn't, immortality by definition, is the inability to die, while longevity just means extension of life by an indefinite amount but implies the possibility of death at any point for any reason.

Comment: @shmosel Y'know, perhaps the path to immortality is obstructed BECAUSE it is forbidden? Also, the blessing could simply refer to immortality of the soul as is emphasized on other parts of the Tanakh, or it could be a cultural expression of good health, & thus this is too inconclusive. You can see this by the quote “My daughter, because you revived my spirit, death shall never rule you” that the focus is on the spirit and not bodily immortality, especially technologically-induced immortality. Also see my response to שלום and what I said about the "obstruction" there, which refutes your reply.

Comment: @DoubleAA perhaps setszu means that they are not the same in the sense that aiming to live as long as possible would involve a lot of differences in research methods and sciences than aiming to completely eradicate death.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that there is any tradition of relating to the cited clause from Gen. 3:22 as a legal prohibition.

My evidence for this is:

- I'm a fairly well-educated Jewish layperson, and I've never heard of such a prohibition.
- If you look on Sefaria for [references to this verse in legal texts](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.3.22?ven=The_Koren_Jerusalem_Bible&lang=bi&with=Halakhah), two come up, and neither relates specifically to this clause about the Tree of Life.

This absence is not surprising, given the structure of the verse. In it, God is reacting to Adam and Eve's transgression of that which was a prohibition for them - eating from the Tree of Knowledge - in a manner designed to prevent them from taking from the Tree of Life and living forever. This implies that such taking is an outcome God wants to prevent, but does not describe a second prohibition, which would presumably be phrased in the second person rather than in the third person.

Comment: Death seems to be a punishment though, and we do have a few places in Chazal that explain why it is important and necessary (and of course, counter examples like Eliyahu that שלום brought, as well as the post-revelation pre-egel madrega...), so it might actually be prohibited to eat from the tree on that account, as it would be forgoing a punishment for a sin.

Comment: Thank you!! I don't think this works tho bc the 1st "evidence" is irrelevant since argument-wise it doesn't matter whether you've heard it or not. The 2nd "evidence" is also irrelevant because technologically-induced bodily immortality hasn't been possible in such days, & thus, its likely that they didn't think it was particularly notable. Absence of writing could mean that they simply missed it, so it's irrelevant. Lastly, a prevention is by definition, a form of prohibition, so this is redundant. Similarly, presumption as per your interpretation is just your personal opinion, not evidence.

Comment: @setszu _is_ a prevention by definition a form of prohibition? Under what parameters? Under some important parameters, they are indeed different.

Comment: @RabbiKaii Functionally speaking, and in this context, they seem to be the same, though prevention is more implicit.

Comment: @setszu if it is not prohibited, but just impossible, then presumably we would be fully permitted to research longevity, and if not, then it becomes a question, so if I have that right, it seemingly is quite relevant to your question

Comment: @RabbiKaii You're operating under the assumption that it's impossible, which is not something that you have justified. Moreover, if it's impossible, why research it in the first place?

Comment: @setszu I'm not operating under any assumptions like that as I'm not trying to answer the question. We're just hypothesising at this stage. Also, to clarify I mean "eternal life" is being presumed to be impossible (as I said, for the sake of argument), however researching longevity in that case would still be useful/moral for whatever gains can be made right? As things remain, if it is possible, then that sounds like the only case where knowing if it is prohibited or not becomes relevant to the question of is the research allowed or not, I think I agree with you on that

Comment: @RabbiKaii Sure I can agree with that line of thinking for now.

Comment: @setszu what do we have to say about eternal life in the Torah? It sounds like it is saying it is impossible for us to achieve with the double-edged sword motif. It does sound like Hashem can grant it, perhaps we have information on how certain blessings and accomplishments and kabbalistic practices can achieve it, but otherwise it sounds like it's probably being made impossible. Worth asking though. In the secular world too, things appear like making the human body live forever is out of reach (entropy etc), but science is full of surprises so who knows. But that's why I said it seems likely

Comment: @RabbiKaii The fact that the tree of life exists by itself implies that immortality is possible for humans, but that we shouldn't reach for it, even in the sense of indefiniteness of death. That being said, HaShem, blessed be He, could and probably would using things like entropy and other methods, destroy the world anyway eventually, but perhaps this could bring it sooner, who knows. Immortality in the truest sense of the word, may only be truly possible in the sense of the spirit and union with Him.

Comment: @setszu I am aware of quite well accepted sources that we will indeed eat of that tree eventually. It's only temporarily blocked. If you'd like those I can try and find the time to look them up for you

Comment: @RabbiKaii Please do, but remember that my point is that it might not be inevitable and unless explicitly granted by G-d, blessed be He, it's illegitimate and we shouldn't eat from it. Finally, the timeline for when we can eat from it is questionable too and we could reach for it too soon, etc.

Comment: @RabbiKaii I'm not familiar with a tradition  that avoiding a punishment is forbidden. I believe there are those who fallaciously suggest that epidurals during labor should be forbidden due to another punishment in this narrative, but I don't think that's part of our legal tradition. (I forget who likened that to considering "And you will be insane" in Deut 28:34 a commandment.)

Comment: @setszu This answer is attempting to report what Jewish legal tradition  has to say about this matter. If I'm right about its silence, then what you're proposing is a novel application of this verse in a practical context, which is not generally a mechanism by which we determine what is prohibited.

Comment: @IsaacMoses interestingly, that supposed epidural prohibition is indeed against Torah, but not because pain in pregnancy is a punishment, but because it is a curse. That's clearly a different in my premises to yours that makes my line of thought different. I don't know if we'd need a tradition to not avoid a Torah proscribed punishment, that seems to be something axiomatic to the concept of justice, but that would be a separate discussion and I'd be happy to be proven wrong on that

Comment: @IsaacMoses I appreciate your reply, but you are making an appeal to tradition fallacy. Who knows, perhaps it is novel, perhaps not. Ultimately, we must pursue the truth to be congruent with HaShem, blessed be He. Also here, it's not merely avoiding a punishment, but also a specific contextual potential prevention and by extension, prohibition.

Comment: @setszu I don't think orthodox judaism has any fallacy associated with "appealing to tradition", nor any contradiction with that and pursuing truth in congruence with Hashem, blessed be He :)

Comment: @RabbiKaii Thank you for sharing your personal opinion, however we must be careful not to make an idol of "tradition" and begin to think of Rabbinical opinions as infallible. We also have to be careful to not confuse personal opinions with authoritative statements about the functions of the world. Appeal to tradition is a general fallacy and like Maimonedes says, even things outside of Judaism can be true potentially, and should be accepted into Jewish frameworks perhaps :P Finally, in some contexts there may not be discongruence but in others, there may be, so we have to be careful  :)

Comment: @setszu does this question post pose a question about Judaism or a proposal for a new idea to add to Judaism? The former is addressable by this community; the latter is not, as the only possible responses would be personal opinion rather than sharing of Judaism-knowledge.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I was more or less just looking for whether anything related to technologically/artificially induced immortality has been written about before in Judaism since we aren't allowed to eat from the tree of life, but I got mostly responses that don't directly answer this and are not particularly useful. I wasn't trying to add a new idea or ask about a new idea per se, but it seems that maybe we might have to sooner or later if nothing has been said on this topic, but that's out of the bounds of what I'm asking for this particular question on the website.

Comment: @setszu If you're seeking anything related that has been written in Judaism, then I don't understand your objection to this answer, which provides some evidence to that exact end.

Comment: @IsaacMoses No it does not. All it does is it provides your opinion and a statement of absence of evidence Please re-read my previous comments to on this that I wrote above.

Answer (score 0):

Rashi on Genesis 3:22 explains that the reason why G-d had a problem with Adam living forever, was because he feared that the coming generations will mistake Adam to be a deity, being that no one was around when he was created (Gur Aryeh), which doesn’t apply in this case, and the sages teach that there were those - such as Elijah - who indeed attained immortality!

But at the end of the day, it’s still in G-d’s hands, and he can always take away this power, like the sages teach regarding Hiram (Ezekiel 28), who was rewarded with immortality, but lost it later on for this reason

Comment: How does it not apply when some of the proponents of such ideas like Yuval Noah Harari discuss how humans are going to become de-facto "gods" or at least "godlike" as technology like AI and biotech life extension converge and essentially enable us to become immortal and give us all sorts of power. Moreover, should this technology ever get lost, but some remanents of these people who used the tech in the past remain, then they will almost certainly be seen as "godlike" and as I said, even the ones like Harari promote such ideas as "Homo Deus", etc. Its clear that ppl can get drunk on this power

Comment: You made an edit, but even in that case, it could still apply as people could forget, intentionally or otherwise, about the past and information transmission could be lost. The comment I wrote above still applies technically.

Comment: Read my comments above where I explain that the same dynamic could play out again today with technology and its potential loss while information transmission could be impaired and those who used the tech while it was still available may think of themselves as "deities" or similar while the others don't remember anything before. Moreover, despite your edit, Elijah didn't remain on Earth or perhaps another planet while being immortal, so his case is different and doesn't apply to technologically and artificially induced immortality.

Comment: Also, for ur final edit, the last line is nonsensical. This is like saying G-d, blessed be He, can take away free will at any time, so it doesn't matter if you murder someone, if He wanted to stop it He would and He can just gilgul them. But of course it does matter, so I can't accept this line of reasoning. Also, the thing with Hiram refers to the immortality of the soul AFAIK, even in Ezekiel 18:4 u can see the talk about the soul & death of it. Finally, even if what the sages say is true, that's a unique case & its simply the opinion/interpretation of sages, not necessarily absolute truth.